# How to reverse the order of two indices of a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like

```
A  T  Value   into    T    A    Value
1  1   32             1    1      32
1  2   33             1    2      55
1  3   34             1    3      96
2  1   55             2    1      33
2  2   56             2    2      56
2  3   57             2    3      97
3  1   96             3    1      34
3  2   97             3    2      57
3  3   98             3    3      98
```

and i want to use reshape (in R) to reshape this object on the left so that the T index comes in the first column and the A index in the second column to get the object on the right. I dont have the melt or cast functions.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want the data to look like.

Comment: its there, from the 3 columns on the left to the ones on the right.

Comment: Only now that it's been edited does it make sense.

Comment: apologies. new to this.

Comment: simple indeed. thanks. not too used to the syntax yet. googled a while then had to ask. smarter now.

Comment: No problem.  As you can see this isn't a job for `reshape`.  `reshape` is used to change the dimensionality (i.e. # of rows and columns) of your dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Let `df` be your `data.frame`.

```
df <- df[order(df$T, df$A), c("T", "A", "Value")]
```

This can be found out easily by googling next time.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just want to sort rows and move columns. If this is your sample input

```
tt<-read.table(text="A  T  Value
1  1   32  
1  2   33  
1  3   34  
2  1   55  
2  2   56  
2  3   57 
3  1   96 
3  2   97 
3  3   98", header=T)
```

you can do

```
tt[order(tt$T, tt$A), c("T","A","Value")]
```